# Display: Hidden and block

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a login / create account on 1 page, stacked ontop of eachother. 
But when you click on the button for "login" or "create account", then it has to hide the opposing one.

So far, I've tried this, without succes.

```
    <script>
        var toggle = function() {
        var mydiv1 = document.getElementById('leftContent');
        var mydiv3 = document.getElementById('leftTitle');

            mydiv2.style.display = 'hidden';
            mydiv4.style.display = 'hidden';
            mydiv3.style.display = 'block';
            mydiv1.style.display = 'block';
        }

        var toggle2 = function() {
        var mydiv2 = document.getElementById('leftContent2');
        var mydiv4 = document.getElementById('leftTitle2');

            mydiv2.style.display = 'block';
            mydiv4.style.display = 'block';
            mydiv3.style.display = 'hidden';
            mydiv1.style.display = 'hidden';
        }
    </script>
```

the mydivs equal 4 divs with 2 of each subject "login" & "create account".
you'd say, why 4 instead of 2, it's because there are also 2 different divs for the titles above them.

I hope you guys can help me out :)
I don't mind trying something entirely different, but i'm hoping to stay away from jquery, and keep it @ just pure js.

Comment: either it should be `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;`

Comment: And both does completely different things, `hidden` will reserve the space of the `visibility: hidden;` element in your document flow, while `display: none;` wont

Answer (score 1):

Use **`display:none`**
or

```
style.display = 'none'
```

Then it will get work !